# Lost lockscreen after uninstalling cinnamon from 13.04, how do I get it back?

Tags: unity, 13.04, cinnamon, lock-screen

Alright, I just received a cinnamon update (presumably to Cinnamon 2.0) and for some reason that update changed my lockscreen, even though I'm using Unity. I wasn't using cinnamon anyway and wanted my Unity lockscreen back (the one that simply presents darkened wallpaper with a clock), so I uninstalled as much of Cinnamon as I dared using Software Centre, then used Synaptic to get rid of the bits of cinnamon (cinnamon-desktop-data ect) left behind.

The trouble is that now, when I press Ctrl+Alt+L, nothing happens, as if the cinnamon lockscreen had overwritten the default unity locker, only to have both removed. How can I get my original lockscreen back?

Cheers in advance!

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Cinnamon packages to me. Please report this to the developers of that package. Did you also check for the keyboard shortcut settings? That may just be reset by Cinnamon, but it's not clear if you also tried to lock the screen using the Unity menu.

Comment: I checked the keyboard shortcut, it is the same as it was before, and just to confirm, I tried to lock the computer with the panel menu, still no luck. It seems that cinnamon had overwritten the default unity lock screen, so what I'm asking is there a way to recover it now that the cinnamon lock screen is gone? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to 13.10. I was able to resolve it by re-enabling the cinnamon-stable ppa and re-installing cinnamon. After that, all is well again. If you aren't using the cinnamon ppa, I recommend it:

https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable

Comment: latest update from cinnamon stable cause problem with 13.04 and 13.10 http://news.softpedia.com/news/Cinnamon-2-0-Corrupts-Unity-on-Ubuntu-13-10-390736.shtml